# Python - French year/number pronunciator

Tags: python

I wanted to try make something of what I'd learned and then thought of making a French year/number pronunciator (text-based). I stumbled upon a few problems like if I have different digits they will all swap places etc. The code I provide now only works for 4 digit numbers as you may see, but I will add the others later. What I came here asking for is why the script output "deux" instead of "douze" if I enter ex. 1992, 1982, 1972 etc? You'll find that in the end of the code.

Since i unfortunately didn't manage to format the code right, I'll have to use pastebin:
But first I warn you; This might cause pain to your eyes. I have yet to understand the difference between if/elif etc. 
http://pastebin.com/ZVU2N9m6

```
year = raw_input("Year: ")

a = "Mille"
b = ""
c = "cent"
d = ""
e = ""

if len(year) == 4: 

    # Decides century
    if year[1] == "9":
        b = " neuf "
    if year[1] == "8":
        b = " huit "
    if year[1] == "7":
        b = " sept "
    if year[1] == "6":
        b = " six "
    if year[1] == "5":
        b = " cinq "
    if year[1] == "4":
        b = " quatre "
    if year[1] == "3":
        b = " trois "
    if year[1] == "2":
        b = " deux "
    if year[1] == "1":
        b = " un "
    if year[1] == "0":
        c = ""

    # Sets decade
    if year[2] == "9":
        d = " quatre-vingt"
    if year[2] == "8":
        d = " quatre-vingt"
    if year[2] == "7":
        d = " soixante"
    if year[2] == "6":
        d = " soixante"
    if year[2] == "5":
        d = " cinquante"
    if year[2] == "4":
        d = " quarante"
    if year[2] == "3":
        d = " trente"
    if year[2] == "2":
        d = " vingt"

    # Sets year 
    if year[3] == "9":
        e = " neuf"
    if year[3] == "8":
        e = " huit"
    if year[3] == "7":
        e = " sept"
    if year[3] == "6":
        e = " six"
    if year[3] == "5":
        e = " cinq"
    if year[3] == "4":
        e = " quatre"
    if year[3] == "3":
        e = " trois"
    if year[3] == "2":
        e = " deux"
    if year[3] == "1":
        e = " et un"
    if year[3] == "0":
        e = ""

    # Sets year for 70s, 80s, 90s (different rule)
    elif year[2] == ("7", "8", "9") and year[3] == "2":
        e = "douze"

    print a + b + c + d + e

else:
    print "Your desired year does not have 4 digits"
```

Comment: Use a hashmap instead of all those `if`s! Basically just a dictionary that says `centurynames = {"1":"un","2":"deux","3":"trois", ... , "9":"neuf"}` then you can do `b = centurynames[year[1]]`

Comment: This is a neat question.  It is better for posterity if you include your code in the question.  It is easier then you think as SO allows some markdown <code> </code>.  If you place those tags on a question and then paste your code between then it should show up properly formatted I would have done it for you  but I don't have enough cred to edit a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `e = "douze"` is never reached.

```
 elif year[2] == ("7", "8", "9") and year[3] == "2":
     e = "douze"
```

I think you ment `year[2] in ("7", "8", "9")`. And with "82" it should indeed be "deux" and not "douce".

---

Actually lists or dicts can make your life a lot easier. The following code snippet produces the french number names from 1 to 99 (excluding "et" as I don't know when to put it):

```
def twoDigits (i):
    if not 0 < i < 100: raise Exception ('Out of bounds')
    below20 = [None, 'un', 'deux', 'trois', 'quatre', 'cinq', 'six', 'sept', 'huit', 'nuef',
        'dix', 'onze', 'douze', 'treize', 'quatorze', 'quinze', 'seize', 'dix-sept', 'dix-huit', 'dix-neuf']
    tens = [None, None, 'vingt', 'trente', 'quarante', 'cinquante', 'soixante', 'soixante', 'quatre-vingt', 'quatre-vingt']
    a, b = i // 10, i % 10
    if a in (1, 7, 9): b += 10
    return ' '.join (x for x in (tens [a], below20 [b] ) if x)

for a in range (1, 100):
    print (a, twoDigits (a) )
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are checking that `year[2] == ("7", "8", "9")` but you need to check that `year[2]` is in `("7", "9")` (with 80s, it shouldn't be *douze*, check comments)

Just change the `elif` and should make the trick:

```
year = raw_input("Year: ")

a = "Mille"
b = ""
c = "cent"
d = ""
e = ""

if len(year) == 4:

        # Decides century
        if year[1] == "9":
                b = " neuf "
        if year[1] == "8":
                b = " huit "
        if year[1] == "7":
                b = " sept "
        if year[1] == "6":
                b = " six "
        if year[1] == "5":
                b = " cinq "
        if year[1] == "4":
                b = " quatre "
        if year[1] == "3":
                b = " trois "
        if year[1] == "2":
                b = " deux "
        if year[1] == "1":
                b = " un "
        if year[1] == "0":
                c = ""

        # Sets decade
        if year[2] == "9":
                d = " quatre-vingt"
        if year[2] == "8":
                d = " quatre-vingt"
        if year[2] == "7":
                d = " soixante"
        if year[2] == "6":
                d = " soixante"
        if year[2] == "5":
                d = " cinquante"
        if year[2] == "4":
                d = " quarante"
        if year[2] == "3":
                d = " trente"
        if year[2] == "2":
                d = " vingt"

        # Sets year
        if year[3] == "9":
                e = " neuf"
        if year[3] == "8":
                e = " huit"
        if year[3] == "7":
                e = " sept"
        if year[3] == "6":
                e = " six"
        if year[3] == "5":
                e = " cinq"
        if year[3] == "4":
                e = " quatre"
        if year[3] == "3":
                e = " trois"
        if year[3] == "2":
                e = " deux"
        if year[3] == "1":
                e = " et un"
        if year[3] == "0":
                e = ""

        # Sets year for 70s, 80s, 90s (different rule)
        elif year[2] in ("7", "9") and year[3] == "2":
                e = " douze"

        print a + b + c + d + e

else:
        print "Your desired year does not have 4 digits"
```

Output:

```
# Year: 1992
# Mille neuf cent quatre-vingt douze
```

By the way, I will recommend you to use a dictionary to make it easier, as @AdamSmith stated in comments

Comment: and 1982 is the same as 1992.

Comment: Sorry, my french isn't really good and I assumed that those part was correct. I have already updated my answer